# vagrant provision ssh issue

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ssh-keys

I have vagrant running scotchbox.  I recently tried to add id_rsa.pub to /vagrant/home/.ssh hoping to be able to ssh in without entering password.  Once I did that it acted the same so I removed it.  Now I was adding another site to the configuration and now I can't do vagrant provision as it gives me the following error.

> SSH authentication failed! This is typically caused by the
>   public/private keypair for the SSH user not being properly set on the
>   guest VM. Please verify that the guest VM is setup with the proper
>   public key, and that the private key path for Vagrant is setup
>   properly as well.

Here is what I get from vagrant ssh-config

```
HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile "/Users/username/.vagrant.d/boxes/scotch-VAGRANTSLASH-box/3.0/virtualbox/vagrant_private_key"
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

Here is my vagrant file.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "scotch/box"
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.10"
    config.vm.hostname = "scotchbox"
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=775", "fmode=664"]


config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.memory = 2048
        v.cpus = 2
    end

    # Optional NFS. Make sure to remove other synced_folder line too
    #config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=666"] }


    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL

            ## Only thing you probably really care about is right here
            DOMAINS=("site1.dev" "site2.dev" "site3.dev" "site4.dev" "site5.dev" "ai.d$

            ## Loop through all sites
            for ((i=0; i < ${#DOMAINS[@]}; i++)); do

                ## Current Domain
                DOMAIN=${DOMAINS[$i]}

                echo "Creating directory for $DOMAIN..."
                mkdir -p /var/www/$DOMAIN/public

                echo "Creating vhost config for $DOMAIN..."
                sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/scotchbox.local.conf /etc/apache2/si$

                echo "Updating vhost config for $DOMAIN..."
                sudo sed -i s,scotchbox.local,$DOMAIN,g /etc/apache2/sites-available/$DOM$
sudo sed -i s,/var/www/public,/var/www/$DOMAIN/public,g /etc/apache2/site$

                echo "Enabling $DOMAIN. Will probably tell you to restart Apache..."
                sudo a2ensite $DOMAIN.conf

            done

        SHELL
end
```

I also get authentication error when doing vagrant up until it times out but box still starts and works and I can ssh into it with password.

I have looked through numerous other questions and have tried some things but nothing seemed to fix it.  Ideally I want to ssh in using keys but would settle just to get back so I can provision it and have to login with password.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out by setting the following in my Vagrantfile to use ssh key that vagrant created when it initialized.

```
config.ssh.private_key_path = "/pathtovagrantfolder/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key"
```